# C++ Winsock - Creating a Console LAN Chat?

Tags: windows-7, mingw, codeblocks

I'm using Jonnie's Winsock tutorial, but am also modifying the code to fit my needs. Is there a straight tutorial for a console LAN chat coded in C++ with Winsock? If not, is there any difference in Jonnie's tutorial for GUI and a console program?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets does not need neither a console nor GUI. It can be used in any kind of program.

To use it in a console program simply put received messages on the console with `std::cout`, and read input with `std::cin` and transmit to the connected program.